# Fixed notifications overlapping

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a simple CSS / JS workaround for fixed notifications?

I have put a JSfiddle together http://jsfiddle.net/Lcq6syLt - as you will see I have two notifications which are fixed, but they are overlapping each other. Is there a way to make them go above each other? and not overlap?

The CSS I am using is:

```
div.notification.fixed {
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0; right: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Comment: put them in a container. fix that container, not each notification.

Comment: what a clever fella! Going to give it a try now :)

Comment: Post it as an answer, IT WORKED!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is make a common container and make that fixed instead.